# jQuery DataTables - What does it take to get it working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I'm trying to implement jQuery DataTables in my MVC 4 app. From reading a couple articles, I was lead to believe it was as simple as:

[image]

However, I'm finding it's not quite that easy. For example, I've read that the HTML tables must be properly formed tables (not what MVC scaffolding creates). I'm not entirely certain what a properly formed table is, and what else is required to get DataTables working.

Can someone summarize everything that must be working just right to get DataTables working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable requires `<th></th>` tags for each table column. And `<table>` tag requires **class="dataTable"** set. `dataTable.css` should be linked. These should make dataTable work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#example').dataTable();
 });
```

Should be initialized after getting the data from server.

Comment: What about thead and tbody tags? Are those required too?

Comment: Yes, `<thead>` and `<tbody>` are required.
For example:
`<table class="dataTable" id="example">`
`<thead>`
`<tr>`
`<th>Id</th><th>Name</th>`
`</tr>`
`</thead>`
`<tbody>`
`<tr>`
`<td>1</td><td>Scott</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>2</td><td>Lee</td>`
`</tr>`
`</tbody>`
`</table>`